# How to apply two functions onto the same string without using ">>"

Tags: haskell, monads

I am writing a function like this.

```
func :: IO()
func = putStr print "func = putStr print"
```

I know it is incorrect but the idea is I want the `putStr` applied onto the string then `print` applied onto the same string `"fun = .."` so that the output would be:

```
func = putStr print "func = putStr print"
```

which is the same as my function definition. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to write a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) (Another Haskell example given in this article too), you could use lambda notation for variable capture.

```
func = (\x -> putStr x >> print x) "func = (\\x -> putStr x >> print x) "
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you are going with the "without using `>>`" part (if that's really the point use `do`-notation), but you can easily write a helper function that applies two functions in sequence to the same input:

```
tee f g s = f s >> g s

func = tee putStr print "..."
```

Also, to just avoid repeating the string, a local variable with `let` or `where` would probably be the easiest:

```
let s = "..."
in  putStr s >> print s
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
doActions str actions = mapM_ ($ str) actions
```